# How can I optimize mysql's date group by speed?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, aggregate-functions, where-clause

```
CREATE TABLE `device_m1000` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`sensor_id` MEDIUMINT(9) NOT NULL,
`ctime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`now_data` FLOAT(12) NOT NULL,
`total_data` FLOAT(12) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
INDEX `sensor_id` (`sensor_id`) USING BTREE,
INDEX `ctime` (`ctime`) USING BTREE) COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=296533;
```

[image]

There are 300,000 data in the table above.
The total_data column always comes in accumulated usage. (A structure that always increases)
If I want to know the usage of "today", I take min value and max value based on today's date and subtract it.

try sql

```
SELECT ROUND((max.v - min.v), 2) total
FROM   (SELECT
               DATE(ctime) `date`,
               sum(total_data)  v
        FROM   device_m1000
        WHERE  ( sensor_id, ctime ) IN (SELECT sensor_id,
                                               MAX(ctime) AS dt
                                        FROM   device_m1000
                                        WHERE  ctime >= '2020-11-23 06:30' and ctime < '2020-11-24 06:30'
                                        GROUP  BY sensor_id
                                        ORDER  BY null)
        group by `date`) max
       INNER JOIN (SELECT
                          DATE(ctime) `date`,
                          sum(total_data)  v
                   FROM   device_m1000
                   WHERE  ( sensor_id, ctime ) IN (SELECT sensor_id,
                                                          MIN(ctime) AS dt
                                                   FROM   device_m1000
                                                   WHERE  ctime >= '2020-11-23 06:30' and ctime < '2020-11-24 06:30'
                                                   GROUP  BY sensor_id
                                                   ORDER  BY null)
                   group by `date`) min
               ON min.`date` = max.`date`;
```

Use the following query to get the data.
However, it simply delays more than 10 seconds in the code at max(ctime).
How can I optimize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- "Row constructors" perform poorly.  (`WHERE (a,b) IN ...`)
- `FLOAT(12)` does not give you 12 significant digits, you get only about 7.
- Is `id` useful?  Or is `(sensor_id, ctime)` unique?  If it is unique, make it the `PRIMARY KEY` and get rid of `id`.
- If you can't make it the PK, have `INDEX(sensor_id, ctime)`.

Back to your question.  Abandon your attempt to put the subtotal in each row.  Virtually any approach will be performaing over a billion operations per second -- because of having to sum up about 30K items from the day for each sensor.

Instead make a separate "summary table" with date, sensor, and total for the day.  Then, when you `INSERT` into the detail table (like what you have), also do

```
INSERT INTO daily_summary (date, sensor, tot)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        tot = VALUES(tot) + ?
```

And use `DOUBLE` for `tot`.  And have `PRIMARY KEY(sensor, date)`

This avoids your subtract and provides a lot of efficiency.

More on summary tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

If you need hourly subtotals, then make it an hourly table instead of daily.  You can efficiently get the daily amount from adding the 24 rows from the hourly summary table.

Comment: Thank you, Rick.
I have a question. What is an effective way to make a summary table?
As you can see from the picture, the sensor data will be accumulated once every 10 seconds.
1. Is trigger appropriate?
2. Create procedures and run events at appropriate times (one minute, five minutes ?)
3. Create a separate program for INSERT

Comment: @Devbreaker - Manually `CREATE TABLE` with (perhaps) 3 columns for your case.  Use the IODKU I spelled out.  It takes care of creating a new row for each sensor for each day.  (I assume you feed it DATE(now_date) for `date`.)  Read my link; also search for my Answers with "summary table".

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want the different between the latest and earliest `total_data` of today for each sensor. If so, you can use window functions like this:

```
select sensor_id, sum(case when rn_desc = 1 then total_data else - total_data end) as total_diff
from (
    select d.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by sensor_id order by ctime) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(partition by sensor_id order by ctime desc) rn_desc
    from device_m1000
    where ctime >= current_date and ctime < current_date + interval 1 day
) t
where 1 in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
group by sensor_id
```

Actually if `total_data` is always increasing, this is simpler (and works in all MySQL versions):

```
select sensor_id, max(total_data) - min(total_data) as total_diff
from device_m1000
where ctime >= current_date and ctime < current_date + interval 1 day
group by sensor_id
```

Then I would recommend the following index: `(ctime, sensor_id, total_data)`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. However, this query took 30 seconds...

Comment: @Devbreaker: are you referring to the first query or the second query?

Comment: @Devbreaker: I added an index suggestion to the answer.